# aiohttp server file upload: request.post UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, aiohttp

I have a web service in Flask which processes uploaded binary data:

```py
@app.route('/v1/something', methods=['POST'])
def v1_something():
    for name in request.files:
        file = request.files[name]
        file.read()
        ...
```

Now I'm rewriting it to AIOHTTP, but having some problem with files processing. My code:

```py
@routes.post('/v1/something')
async def v1_something(request):
    files = await request.post()
    for name in files:
        file = files[name]
        file.read()
        ...
```

I get an error at the line `await request.post()`:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 14: invalid start byte

Looks like AIOHTTP tries to read given binary as a text. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to read the source code and found that `request.post()` intended for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `multipart/form-data`, that's why it always tries to parse given data as a text. I also found that I should use `request.multipart()`:

```py
@routes.post('/v1/something')
async def v1_something(request):
    async for obj in (await request.multipart()):
        # obj is an instance of aiohttp.multipart.BodyPartReader
        if obj.filename is not None:  # to pass non-files
            file = BytesIO(await obj.read())
            ...
```